# How to merge data in a json by a name property in typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm working on a project and I need to parse data sent by a server. So I have a big JSON with OTA name with a data linked to it. Here is my Array :

```
0: {name: "Airbnb", value: 48}
1: {name: "Booking.com", value: 6}
2: {name: "Air Rental", value: 2}
3: {name: "Airbnb", value: 50}
4: {name: "Booking.com", value: 14}
5: {name: "Air Rental", value: 1}
6: {name: "Airbnb", value: 38}
7: {name: "Air Rental", value: 3}
8: {name: "Booking.com", value: 6}
9: {name: "HomeAway", value: 1}
10: {name: "Airbnb", value: 40}
11: {name: "HomeAway", value: 1}
12: {name: "Booking.com", value: 2}
13: {name: "Air Rental", value: 2}
14: {name: "Airbnb", value: 48}
15: {name: "Booking.com", value: 6}
16: {name: "Air Rental", value: 0}
17: {name: "Airbnb", value: 11}
18: {name: "Air Rental", value: 1}
19: {name: "Airbnb", value: 17}
20: {name: "Booking.com", value: 2}
21: {name: "Air Rental", value: 0}
22: {name: "Airbnb", value: 17}
23: {name: "Booking.com", value: 1}
24: {name: "Misterbnb", value: 2}
25: {name: "Air Rental", value: 2}
26: {name: "Airbnb", value: 43}
27: {name: "Booking.com", value: 23}
28: {name: "Misterbnb", value: 1}
29: {name: "Air Rental", value: 1}
30: {name: "Booking.com", value: 26}
...
```

As you can see, I have multiple "Airbnb" or "Booking.com" linked with a value, for example. I just wanted to know if their is an easy way to merge/sum all those values using the name linked to it.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the best way is to use lodash reduce
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.13#reduce

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using [**`reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Example:

```js
const jsonData = [{
    name: "Airbnb",
    value: 48
  },
  {
    name: "Booking.com",
    value: 6
  },
  {
    name: "Air Rental",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Airbnb",
    value: 50
  },
  {
    name: "Booking.com",
    value: 14
  },
  {
    name: "Air Rental",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Airbnb",
    value: 38
  },
  {
    name: "Air Rental",
    value: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Booking.com",
    value: 6
  },
  {
    name: "HomeAway",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Airbnb",
    value: 40
  },
  {
    name: "HomeAway",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Booking.com",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Air Rental",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Airbnb",
    value: 48
  },
  {
    name: "Booking.com",
    value: 6
  },
  {
    name: "Air Rental",
    value: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Airbnb",
    value: 11
  },
  {
    name: "Air Rental",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Airbnb",
    value: 17
  },
  {
    name: "Booking.com",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Air Rental",
    value: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Airbnb",
    value: 17
  },
  {
    name: "Booking.com",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Misterbnb",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Air Rental",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Airbnb",
    value: 43
  },
  {
    name: "Booking.com",
    value: 23
  },
  {
    name: "Misterbnb",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Air Rental",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Booking.com",
    value: 26
  },
];

const reducedData = jsonData.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  if (accumulator[currentValue.name]) {
    accumulator[currentValue.name] += currentValue.value;
  } else {
    accumulator[currentValue.name] = currentValue.value;
  }
  return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(reducedData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use typed dictionary:

```js
const array = [
    {name: "Airbnb", value: 48},
    {name: "Booking.com", value: 6},
    {name: "Air Rental", value: 2},
    {name: "Airbnb", value: 50},
    {name: "Booking.com", value: 14}
];

const result: { [name: string]: number } = {};
for (const entry of array) {
  // Typed dictionary initialization if needed.
  if (!result[entry.name]) {
    result[entry.name] = 0;
  }
  result[entry.name] += entry.value;
}

console.log(result);
```

Or if you need to keep your structure you could do something like:

```js
const array = [
    {name: "Airbnb", value: 48},
    {name: "Booking.com", value: 6},
    {name: "Air Rental", value: 2},
    {name: "Airbnb", value: 50},
    {name: "Booking.com", value: 14}
];

const results: { name: string; value: number }[] = [];
for (const entry of array) {
  const found = results.find(e => e.name == entry.name);
  if (found) {
    found.value += entry.value;
  } else {
    results.push(entry);
  }
}

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thanks ! I used the second code you gaved me, it worked, but their is on thing I don't understand, what's the "e" you've put as argument of the find function ?

Comment: The `e` represents a single element from the `results` array.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate loop on each element and merge number value if name already exist.

```
array.forEach(a => {
result[a.name]= (result[a.name] + a.number)  || a.number;
});
```

OR you can use reduce function to iterate each and every element of array with previous result.

```
result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
r[a.name] = r[a.name] || [];
r[a.name].push(a.number);
return r;
}, Object.create(null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with lodash, as mentioned in my first comment

```
this.data = [
      {name: "Airbnb", value: 48},
      {name: "Booking.com", value: 6},
      {name: "Air Rental", value: 2},
      {name: "Airbnb", value: 50},
      {name: "Booking.com", value: 14},
      {name: "Air Rental", value: 1},
      {name: "Airbnb", value: 38},
      {name: "Air Rental", value: 3},
      {name: "Booking.com", value: 6},
      {name: "HomeAway", value: 1},
      {name: "Airbnb", value: 40},
      {name: "HomeAway", value: 1},
      {name: "Booking.com", value: 2},
      {name: "Air Rental", value: 2},
      {name: "Airbnb", value: 48},
      {name: "Booking.com", value: 6},
      {name: "Air Rental", value: 0},
      {name: "Airbnb", value: 11},
      {name: "Air Rental", value: 1},
      {name: "Airbnb", value: 17},
      {name: "Booking.com", value: 2},
      {name: "Air Rental", value: 0},
      {name: "Airbnb", value: 17},
      {name: "Booking.com", value: 1},
      {name: "Misterbnb", value: 2},
      {name: "Air Rental", value: 2},
      {name: "Airbnb", value: 43},
      {name: "Booking.com", value: 23},
      {name: "Misterbnb", value: 1},
      {name: "Air Rental", value: 1},
      {name: "Booking.com", value: 26},
    ];

    const result = _.reduce(this.data, (dataHolder, entry) => {
      if(dataHolder[entry.name]) {
        dataHolder[entry.name] += entry.value;
      } else {
        dataHolder[entry.name] = entry.value;
      }

      return dataHolder
    }, {});

    console.log(result);
```

prints

```
{Airbnb: 312, Booking.com: 86, Air Rental: 12, HomeAway: 2…}
Air Rental: 12
Airbnb: 312
Booking.com: 86
HomeAway: 2
Misterbnb: 3
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: No need for lodash, `reduce` exists since javascript 1.8.